# clBuildProgram() always returns -11 on Mac (Catalina) using clang; clGetProgramBuildInfo() returns empty string

Tags: c, clang, gpu, opencl, macos-catalina

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro running macOS Catalina (10.16.7), the machine has an AMD Radeon Pro 5300M along with onboard Intel UHD Graphics. I'm trying to build a "Hello World" OpenCL program using Clang (I'm able to query platform and device information fine) but I can never get `clBuildProgram` to successfully complete. If I try and compile and run the program on another (non mac) machine it compiles and runs fine.

In the code below I guess I'm getting the device for the CPU, but I'll get the same error regardless of the device I choose. I've also get the same error if I try and compile and run several other "Hello World" openCL example I've downloaded from the internet. So I figure there's either something wrong with how I'm compiling the program or something else with my configuration. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define MAX_NUM_DEVICES_PER_PLATFORM 128
#define MEM_SIZE 128

int main() {
    static const char source[] =
        "__kernel void hello(__global char* string)\n"
        "{\n"
        "    string[0] = 'H';  string[1] = 'e'; string[2] = 'l';  string[3] = 'l';\n"
        "    string[4] = 'o';  string[5] = ','; string[6] = ' ';  string[7] = 'W';\n"
        "    string[8] = 'o';  string[9] = 'r'; string[10] = 'l'; string[11] = 'd';\n"
        "    string[12] = '!'; string[13] = '\\0';\n"
        "}";

    // Get OpenCL device and create an OpenCL context
    cl_platform_id platforms;  cl_uint numPlatforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platforms, &numPlatforms);

    cl_uint numDevices;  cl_device_id devices[MAX_NUM_DEVICES_PER_PLATFORM];
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, MAX_NUM_DEVICES_PER_PLATFORM, devices, &numDevices);
    cl_device_id device = devices[0];

    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    cl_command_queue commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &ret);
    cl_mem memBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, MEM_SIZE * sizeof(char), NULL, NULL);

    // Build program
    size_t programSize;
    const char *src=source;
    size_t srcsize = strlen(source);
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&src, &srcsize, NULL);

    if(program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create OpenCL program.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    cl_int errNum = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (errNum != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to build OpenCL program (error %i)\n", errNum);
        size_t len = 0;
        cl_int ret = CL_SUCCESS;
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &len);
        char *buffer = calloc(len, sizeof(char));
        ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, len, buffer, NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", buffer);
        exit(1);
    }

    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "hello", NULL);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&memBuffer);

    // Run the kernel
    ret = clEnqueueTask(commandQueue, kernel, 0, NULL,NULL);
     
    // Get results from memory buffer
    char string[MEM_SIZE];
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue, memBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0,
        MEM_SIZE * sizeof(char),string, 0, NULL, NULL);
    puts(string);

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run I get the following output:

```
+ clang hello.c -framework opencl -o hello
+ ./hello
Unable to build OpenCL program (error -11)
Error:
```

Comment: Try Apple's sample, it has complete Xcode project https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/

Answer (score 0):

Building host code using clang or other compiler has nothing to do with what compiler is being used to build OpenCL kernel.

The program tries to build OpenCL kernel for all available OpenCL platforms, which in this case can be AMD GPU, Intel GPU and Intel CPU. I would suggest to try building for one specific instead, for example:

```
ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, "-I. -Werror", NULL, NULL);
```

Apart from that there are many posts about problems with OpenCL implementation on Mac, you may want to search for that too.